# Is there any config that can be enabled to set a precision for Double value in cassandra datastax java driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Cassandra internally stores the Double values as it is. Like how cqlsh supports settings where we can change the precision, is there any similar config in datastax java driver to set the precision?

One way will be to use the DecimalFormat in the Getter of the variable and set the precision. But want to know if datastax driver has provided any such way to simplify the precision setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options provided by `cqlsh` are only used for displaying the data - internally all data are handled as normal doubles.

The same is for DataStax Java driver - it just returns the double, and it's responsibility of developer to convert it into that representation that is most appropriate for user. So you need to use corresponding code to format double into string with given precision.